# when more foreign keys and need to insert is it good to use native @Query instead of JPA managed way

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

There is a table with 3 foreign keys to three tables.
To do an insert using JPA, is it suggested/performant to

> query individual tables(having foreign key relations) and create
>   respecitve objects and do a .save()

?
or

> use native @Query(), with @Transactional and @Modifying?

for making an insert, i am making 3 calls to DB to get respective objects/details and use them for insertion. so total 4 calls.

If i use native Query, i have the id's required(getting from client) i can do it in one query.

so, is it good to do in JPA way or use native query? which is good in view of performance?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the primary keys of the dependencies you can call EntityManager.getReference().

This will return a placeholder that you can use to set as the dependencies in your entity. That way no SQL statement is executed for the dependencies.

From the API Doc:

```
<T> T getReference(Class<T> entityClass,
                   Object primaryKey)

Get an instance, whose state may be lazily fetched. 
If the requested instance does not exist in the database, the EntityNotFoundException
is thrown when the instance state is first accessed. 
(The persistence provider runtime is permitted to throw the EntityNotFoundException when getReference is called.) 
The application should not expect that the instance state will be available upon detachment, 
unless it was accessed by the application while the entity manager was open.

Parameters:
entityClass - entity class
primaryKey - primary key
Returns:
the found entity instance

Throws:
IllegalArgumentException - if the first argument does not denote an entity type or the second argument is not a valid type for that entity's primary key or is null
EntityNotFoundException - if the entity state cannot be accessed
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#getReference-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object-